Whitehead theorem and relative homotopy.
I found that some authors define homotopy relative to a subspace, as in wikipedia, and some authors define it like in Hatcher's book.
Could someone please explain Hatcher's definition in more detail? Maybe some non-trivial examples would be very helpful.
In the proof of Whitehead's theorem, Hatcher uses the Compression Lemma to prove the special case.
Hatcher wrote in Page 347 :
"Applying the lemma to the identity map $(Y,X) \rightarrow (Y,X)$ then yields a deformation retraction of $Y$ onto $X$".
But I can not see how this gives a deformation retraction.
Appealing to the Compression Lemma (Page 346), we have the identity map $1_{Y}$ is homotopic rel $X$ to a map $g: Y \rightarrow X$ (which we view as a map from $Y$ to $Y$ by composing the inclusion map).
So, let $g_t$ be the homotopy, with $g_0 = 1_{Y}$ and $g_1 = g$.
Then, we need to show that $g_t$ restricted on $X$ is the identity map for all $t$. (Definition of deformation retraction is on Page 2)
But I can not see how this is the case, because, with Hatcher's definition, it just tells us that $g_t$ restricted to $X$ is independent of $t$. It maybe identity, but it need not be the identity, so I'm not able to see how.

Just check what is the map $g_t|X$ at $t=0$.

Oh my god, thank you so much! Everything clicks now. (And sorry for the stupid question)
